# Django + Nginx Unable to serve media files

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have two servers: the first for Nginx and the second for Django + media files.

```
Nginx server IP: xxx.xx.xx.1
Django + media files server IP: xxx.xx.xx.2
```

In Django's `settings.py` file, my media path configurations:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

In the first server, my Nginx configurations:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;

        location /media/ {
                proxy_pass http://xxx.xx.xx.2/;
        }

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://xxx.xx.xx.2:8000/;
        }
}
```

In the second server, where the media files are placed, my Nginx configurations:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name xxx.xx.xx.2;

        location /media/ {
                alias /home/sadm/Desktop/{project_name}/media;
        }
```

However, when trying to access `example.com/media/images/my_image.jpg`, I get a `404` error.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it work if you go straight to server2/media?

Comment: @DanielRoseman No, it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be minute, but I don't think you should have `/media` at the end of your alias.
Try this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name xxx.xx.xx.2;

        location /media/ {
                root /home/sadm/Desktop/{project_name};
        }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. By any chance, would me placing this configuration under `/etc/nginx/sites-available/{project_name}` be the problem? I did not make any changes to the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file.

Comment: I doubt that would be a problem. Is it also in `sites-enabled`?

Comment: That was the problem! Added a `{project_name}` file in `sites-enabled`, and I'm able to access `http://xxx.xx.xx.2/media/images/my_image.jpg`! However, `example.com/media/images/my_image.jpg` still gives a `404` error. All other pages are showing up correctly on the website though.

Comment: maybe the proxy pass should be `http://xxx.xx.xx.2/media/`? Just guessing though!

Comment: I finally managed to get it to work! The problem lies in the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` folder of the first server (the Nginx server) - it has a `default` file and a `{project_name}` file. I had previously placed the Nginx configurations under the `{project_name}` file. To solve the problem, I also had to add the proxy pass to `http://xxx.xx.xx.2` for media files in the `default` file. Thanks so much for your help yesterday!

Comment: Hey, this is random (and late), but I was setting up two new servers today with the same configurations, and was met with the same problem again. This time, I followed your suggestions - on my Django server, I set the static files location to `root /home/sadm/Desktop/{project_name}` and on the Nginx server, I proxy pass to `http://xxx.xx.xx.2/media/`. This worked perfectly! Not sure why I didn't work previously, but I feel that this configuration is better than my previous hack, so I'm accepting your answer! Thank you so much for your help once again!